# Calcular el numero de dias entre la ultima fecha y la penultima

Tags: mysql, sql, lógica

tengo este codigo, pero me gustaria sacar la diferencia en dias entre la ultima fecha (MAX_RECORD_DATE) y la penultima fecha de ese RECORD_DATE solo que no tengo muy claro como sacar la penultima fecha

```
SELECT
    COMP_ID,
    ITEM,
    SUPP_CODE,
    MFG_PARTNO,
    RECORD_DATE,
    Max(CALC_LEAD_TIME) AS  MAX_CALC_LEAD_TIME,
    MAX(RECORD_DATE) AS MAX_RECORD_DATE
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY COMP_ID, ITEM, SUPP_CODE, MFG_PARTNO, RECORD_DATE
```

lo que pensaba es sacar el MAX_RECORD_DATE y el penultimo dia y usarlos en un DATEDIFF

He visto en otros posts que muchos recomiendan crear una tabla y de ahi un row number y sacar el penultimo, pero en este caso yo no puedo crear, solo hacer consultas, agradeceria mucho su ayuda!!

Ejemplo datos obtenidos

| Item | Record date |
| --- | --- |
| 58JT7 | 2022-10-01 |
| 884HW | 2022-11-01 |
| 33MN5 | 2022-01-17 |

Ejemplo, datos esperados

| Item | Record date | max Date | Penultime date | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58JT7 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-10-01 | 30 |
| 884HW | 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-10-01 | 30 |
| 33MN5 | 2022-01-17 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-10-01 | 30 |

bueno, el numero de diferencia es del mes, puse 30 para que mas o menos se comprenda

Comment: Agrega ejemplos de conjunto de datos y del resultado esperado.

Comment: Cierto! modificado!!

Comment: Si ordenas DESC, con `LIMIT 1,1` obtienes el penúltimo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías realizar con una subconsulta para obtener la penúltima fecha que sería la fecha más reciente anterior a la ultima fecha y para cada combianación de COMP_ID, ITEM, SUPP_CODE y MFG_PARTNO. y posterior utilizas utilizas la función DATEIF ´para que calcules la diferencia en días entra la ultima y la penultima fecha.

```
SELECT
    COMP_ID,
    ITEM,
    SUPP_CODE,
    MFG_PARTNO,
    MAX(RECORD_DATE) AS MAX_RECORD_DATE,
    (
        SELECT MAX(RECORD_DATE)
        FROM Tabla
        WHERE COMP_ID = t.COMP_ID
        AND ITEM = t.ITEM
        AND SUPP_CODE = t.SUPP_CODE
        AND MFG_PARTNO = t.MFG_PARTNO
        AND RECORD_DATE < MAX(t.RECORD_DATE)
    ) AS PENULTIMATE_RECORD_DATE,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, (
        SELECT MAX(RECORD_DATE)
        FROM Tabla
        WHERE COMP_ID = t.COMP_ID
        AND ITEM = t.ITEM
        AND SUPP_CODE = t.SUPP_CODE
        AND MFG_PARTNO = t.MFG_PARTNO
        AND RECORD_DATE < MAX(t.RECORD_DATE)
    ), MAX(RECORD_DATE)) AS DIFFERENCE_IN_DAYS
FROM Tabla t
GROUP BY COMP_ID, ITEM, SUPP_CODE, MFG_PARTNO, RECORD_DATE
```

Comment: Gracias Neto, aqui tengo una duda, porque no poner DATEDIFF (DAY, PENULTIMATE_RECORD_DATE, MAX(RECORD_DATE)) AS DIFFERENCE_IN_DAYS... o si es necesario poner todo el codigo de nuevo?

Comment: No es necesario poner todo el código de nuevo si lo quieres optimizado lo podrías poner como comentas, yo  lo puse así para que entiendas pero si ya tienes conocimientos de sql puedes poner de manera optimizada como comentas que sería lo ideal

Comment: lo que noto es que en este ejemplo obtengo el MAX_RECORD_DATE pero por linea, no el maximo de todos los items, asi que decidi hacer un CTE solo para el MAX_RECORD_DATE (group by item etc...) y asi obtengo la fecha mas reciente, sin embargo, aqui tendria que hacer un subquery donde obtenga el penultimo valor sin agrupar el record date, es posible hacerlo asi?

Comment: me pasaron un ejemplo de otro numero que usamos, pero no se si aplicaria igual `LAST_VALUE(MAX_CALC_LEAD_TIME) OVER( PARTITION BY COMP_ID, ITEM, SUPP_CODE, MFG_PARTNO ORDER BY RECORD_DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding ) AS PREVIOUS_CALC_LEAD_TIME`